# Referring DLL from in a project with depending DLL already present

Tags: c#, dll, interop

I have a DLL name `A.dll` which is in project `B`. Now I create a project(C# library) name `C` which refers `A.dll` for some functionalities. I compiled C and copied its dll(`C.dll`) into project `B` and add reference to it. Now when I'm trying to compile the project `B`, I get an error `Cannot embed interop types from assembly 'c:\Users\Desktop\Properties\C.dll' because it is missing either the 'ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' attribute or the 'PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute' attribute"`.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Odd problem.  If this is actually a COM server written in a native language.  But since you can't tell us what is special about this DLL, simply force it to not be embedded.  Select the reference and set its "Embed Interop Types" property to False.

Comment: @HansPassant, for which DLL, I should set that?